# Why isn't "findIndex" finding my first matching array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

On my Firefox web console, I enter the following JS

```
const scoreTierMins = [90, 70, 50, 30, 10, 0]; 
const pctScore = 75;
```

I want to find the index of the first element in the "scoreTierMins" array that is greater than or equal to "pctScore".  So I tried this

```
scoreTierMins.findIndex(function(el) {el >= pctScore});
```

but I get the result "-1".  What else am I missing?  Shouldn't the result be "1" because "70" is the first element that matches the condition?

Comment: You're missing a `return`.

Comment: aka: `scoreTierMins.findIndex(el => el >= pctScore)`

Comment: Also the result should be 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't *returning* the result of the comparison. Though you put the expression `el >= pctScore` in the function body, without a return statement it's just an expression that does nothing and whose value is discarded. It's as if you wrote this function:

```
function compareElements(el) {
  el >= pctScore;
}
```

When you write it out it should be clear that it's not doing anything.

Instead, return the condition like so:

```js
const scoreTierMins = [90, 70, 50, 30, 10, 0]; 
const pctScore = 75; 

let index = scoreTierMins.findIndex(function(el) {return el >= pctScore}); 
console.log(index);
```

Or use ES6 arrow functions to be more concise: `scoreTierMins.findIndex(el => el >= pctScore)` - when the body of an arrow function is just an expression, it is implicitly unwrapped to `el => { return el >= pctScore }`.

Comment: Just use a lambda expression, or utilize new-lines to show _WHY_ they need the return. Just throwing it in there does not point out their error in trying to write it all on one line.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I did recommend an arrow function under the code snippet. I also do point out the error in the first paragraph before introducing the fixed code, but I took your suggestion on writing out the function in full form to show that it looks incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The 'findIndex callback' should return a 'boolean'. In your case, return the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem searching through test of Regular expression, here the Javascript (FireFox) log:

```
re = new RegExp("^width\\s*[:=]|^width$","gi");
/^width\s*[:=]|^width$/gi

h = ["width : 250","Height","300","top"]
Array(4) [ "width : 250", "Height", "300", "top" ]

h.findIndex(el => re.test(el))
0
h.findIndex(el => re.test(el))
-1
h.findIndex(el => re.test(el))
0
h.findIndex(el => re.test(el))
-1
```

If instead of "width" I search for "height" or "width" is not the first item I always get the correct answer.

I got the correct results by eliminating the g (global) flag from the regular expression because with this flag:

> RegExp objects are stateful when they have the global or sticky flags set